# Calculate $\int ^{4\pi} _{-4\pi} \frac{(\sin x)^2-(\sin x)^4}{1-(\sin x)^4}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, definite-integrals

> Calculate $$\int ^{4\pi} _{-4\pi} \frac{(\sin x)^2-(\sin x)^4}{1-(\sin x)^4}dx$$

I tried to do this task in several ways, but none of them proved to be effective.
 For example:

$$\int ^{4\pi} _{-4\pi} \frac{(\sin x)^2-(\sin x)^4}{1-(\sin x)^4}dx=\int ^{4\pi} _{-4\pi} \frac{(\sin x)^2(1-(\sin x)^2)}{1-(\sin x)^4}dx=\int ^{4\pi} _{-4\pi} \frac{(\sin x)^2}{1+(\sin x)^2}dx=\int ^{4\pi} _{-4\pi} \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{(\sin x)^2}}dx$$

However I don't know what I can do the next to finish this task. When I use $u=(\sin x)^2 $ I have $du=\cos x dx$ so I can't use it.
Have you got some intelligent way to do this task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing $x=\arctan t$ and $\mathrm dx=\frac1{1+t^2}\,\mathrm dt$, you get$$\int\frac{\sin^2x}{1+\sin^2x}\,\mathrm dx=\int\frac{t^2}{2 t^4+3 t^2+1}\,\mathrm dt=\int\frac{1}{t^2+1}-\frac{1}{2 t^2+1}\,\mathrm dt.$$Can you take it from here?

Comment: Ok, but $\tan x$ is not continuous at $[-4\pi, 4\pi]$. If use proposition @JohnHughes I have $[0,\pi]$ but continued $\tan x$ is not continuous. In that case, can I use it? After substituting $ t $ I have an integral from $ 0 $ to $ 0 $ which is not correct

Comment: Your function is periodic with period $\pi$. So, your integral is equal to $8$ times the integral  from $-\frac\pi2$ to $\frac\pi2$. And on $\left(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right)$ there is no problem: $\tan$ is continuous there.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:
$$ \frac{(\sin x)^2-(\sin x)^4}{1-(\sin x)^4}= 1-\frac{1-\sin^2 x}{1-(\sin x)^4}=1-\frac{1}{1+\sin^2x}=1-\frac{\sec^2x}{1+2\tan^2x}$$

Answer (score 1):

You're integrating a polynomial in $\sin$ and $\cos$; the $\tan(t/2)$ substitution (http://www-math.mit.edu/~djk/18_01/chapter24/section03.html) will convert this to a rational function of a variable $t$.

(You can also slightly simplify by noting that your integrand is an even function, so you can just double the integral from $0$ to $4\pi$; then you can note that the integrand is periodic with period $\pi$, so you get $8$ times the integral from $0$ to $\pi$. But probably neither of these saves much effort once you do the $\tan(t/2)$ substitution.)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Bioche's rules say you should  set $t=\tan x$. Indeed, with some trigonometry,
$$\frac{\sin^2x}{1+\sin^2x}=\frac{\cfrac{t^2}{1+t^2}}{1+\cfrac{t^2}{1+t^2}}=\cfrac{t^2}{1+2t^2},\qquad\mathrm dx=\frac{\mathrm dt}{1+t^2},$$
 so the indefinite integral becomes
$$\int\frac{t^2\,\mathrm dt}{(1+2t^2)(1+t^2)}$$
Can you continue?

Comment: Ok, but $\tan x$ is not continuous at $[-4\pi, 4\pi]$. If use proposition @JohnHughes I have $[0,\pi]$ but continued $\tan x$ is not continuous. In that case, can I use it? After substituting $ t $ I have an integral from $ 0 $ to $ 0 $ which is not correct

Comment: You can obtain the antiderivative of the integrand in terms of $x$, and use it to calculate the definite integral without changing the integration bounds.